# Draw canvas on layout without hiding elements on UI

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, draw

I use the method below to draw something on the layout, it works fine, the rectangle shows up, but everything else on the UI becomes invisible, even if the canvas are NOT ON the UI element.

I could not find any similar problem with a solution so I came to ask you guys.

I suspect it's something with the `setContentView(myview)` and it's super simple but I am stucked.

Here is my code:

```
// MyView.java
public class MyView extends View {
Paint paint;
Path path;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
}


// MainActivity: void onCreate()

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
MyView myview = new MyView(getBaseContext());
setContentView(myview);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use baseContext for a veiw-  use the activity context, because a view is bound to an activity.  Also, you should add the view to the layout (either programatically or preferably in xml), not set the content view twice (since the second will overwrite the first).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it is because of `setContentView(myview);`.

The method `setContentView` sets the passed view (or layout) as the visible content of the activity.

In your case the new custom view replaces your layout which was inflated earlier.

In order to display both your UI elements and Custom view, add other two constructors in your custom view and add the custom view from XML as you would add a simple `TextView`.

Constructors of the custom view should be defined like below:

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

Or you can take a reference of some layout such as `LinearLayout`, etc and add the instance of custom view using `layout.addView(myView);`

Comment: Could you help me with how to call the constructor from the mainactivity?

Comment: Your way of calling the constructor from the main activity is okay. But you can't use `setContentView` like that. Alternatively, without using constructor, after you put in all 3 constructors, you can add your custom view from XML, and get the reference using `findViewById`.